# Easy ways to calculate matrix exponential of a particular $4\times 4$ matrix

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-exponential

Wondering how to find the matrix exponential of the following matrix without having to do through the long process of finding eigenvalues/eigenvectors and Jordan forms.  Is there a quicker way to do it using Sine/Cosine ?

If 
$$A= \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
                     1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
                     1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
                     1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Find $e^{tA}$.

Comment: I'm afraid I am unfamiliar

Comment: you want a quicker way involving only pen and paper or computer based would also work for you?

Comment: Apologies, I should have specified this is a question that appeared on my Differential Equations Exam so it would have to be pen and paper. I am looking for a different way to do it because the 'long way' calculating the characteristic polynomial etc. took too long in the exam causing me to run out of time.

Comment: Pen and paper work implies that such matrix has some particular properties that could be exploited. In this question, all-1 matrix has an easily calculated powers.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\boldsymbol A = \boldsymbol U - \boldsymbol I_4$. Simple calculations show that $\boldsymbol U^n = 4^{n-1} \boldsymbol U$. Now for every $n \in \mathbb N^*$:
\begin{align*}
\boldsymbol A^n =( \boldsymbol U - \boldsymbol I_4)^n &= \sum_0^n \binom n j \boldsymbol U^{j} (-1)^{n-j} \boldsymbol I \\
&=(-1)^n \boldsymbol I + \sum_1^n \binom n j 4^{j-1}(-1)^{n-j} \boldsymbol U \\
&= (-1)^n\boldsymbol I + \frac 14 \sum_0^n \binom n j 4^j (-1)^{n-j} \boldsymbol U - (-1)^n \boldsymbol U /4 \\
&= \frac 14 (4-1)^n \boldsymbol U + (-1)^n\boldsymbol I - (-1)^n \boldsymbol U/4 \\
&= \frac 14 \cdot (3^n - (-1)^n) \boldsymbol U + (-1)^n\boldsymbol I  
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\exp(t\boldsymbol A) &= \sum_0^\infty \frac 1 {n!} t^n\boldsymbol A^n \\
&= \sum_0^\infty \frac {t^n}{4n!} (3^n \boldsymbol U - (-1)^n \boldsymbol U + 4(-1)^n\boldsymbol I) \\
&= \frac 14 (\mathrm e^{3t} - \mathrm e^{-t}) \boldsymbol U + \mathrm e^{-t}\boldsymbol I.
\end{align*}

Comment: I don't think this can be right---$\frac{1}{4} e^{3t} {\bf U}$ is degenerate, but the exponential of a matrix is always invertible.

Comment: $U^n=4^{n-1}U$ is not true for $n=0$ (in the summation $\sum_0^n$).

Comment: @Travis Thanks, i fixed it!

Comment: @A.Γ. Thanks, i fixed it!

Answer (score 5):

Let $u$ be the $4\times 1$ matrix with all entries equal to $1$.  Let $u'$ be its transpose. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
A &=uu'-I\ ,\\
A+I &=uu'\ ,\\
4 &=u'u\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Then
$$
e^{tA}=e^{-tI+t(A+I)}=e^{-tI}\cdot e^{t(A+I)}=e^{-t}\cdot e^{t\,uu'}\ .
$$
Now the powers of $uu'$ are easily computed. For instance $(uu')^2=uu'\ uu'=u\ u'u\ u'=4uu'$, inductively $(uu')^{n+1}=4^n\, uu'$. The exponential of $t\,uu'$ is then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\exp(tuu')
&=
I
+\frac 1{1!}t\, uu'
+\frac 1{2!}t^2\, 4\, uu'
+\frac 1{3!}t^3\, 4^2\, uu'
+\frac 1{4!}t^4\, 4^3\, uu'
+\frac 1{5!}t^5\, 4^4\, uu'
+\dots
\\
&=
I
+
\frac 14\left(
 \frac 1{1!}t\, 4
+\frac 1{2!}t^2\, 4^2
+\frac 1{3!}t^3\, 4^3
+\frac 1{4!}t^4\, 4^4
+\frac 1{5!}t^5\, 4^5
+\dots
\right)\, uu'
\\
&=
I +
\frac 14(e^{4t}-1)\,uu'
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The above $uu'$ is the matrix with ones as entries.

From here we get the needed formula, as confirmed by [sage](http://www.sagemath.org):

```
sage: A = matrix( QQ, 4,4, [0,1,1,1, 1,0,1,1, 1,1,0,1, 1,1,1,0] )
sage: A
[0 1 1 1]
[1 0 1 1]
[1 1 0 1]
[1 1 1 0]
sage: var('t');
sage: exp(t*A)
[1/4*(e^(4*t) + 3)*e^(-t) 1/4*(e^(4*t) - 1)*e^(-t) 1/4*(e^(4*t) - 1)*e^(-t) 1/4*(e^(4*t) - 1)*e^(-t)]
[1/4*(e^(4*t) - 1)*e^(-t) 1/4*(e^(4*t) + 3)*e^(-t) 1/4*(e^(4*t) - 1)*e^(-t) 1/4*(e^(4*t) - 1)*e^(-t)]
[1/4*(e^(4*t) - 1)*e^(-t) 1/4*(e^(4*t) - 1)*e^(-t) 1/4*(e^(4*t) + 3)*e^(-t) 1/4*(e^(4*t) - 1)*e^(-t)]
[1/4*(e^(4*t) - 1)*e^(-t) 1/4*(e^(4*t) - 1)*e^(-t) 1/4*(e^(4*t) - 1)*e^(-t) 1/4*(e^(4*t) + 3)*e^(-t)]
sage: latex(_)
```

$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
\frac{1}{4} \, {\left(e^{\left(4 \, t\right)} + 3\right)} e^{\left(-t\right)} & \frac{1}{4} \, {\left(e^{\left(4 \, t\right)} - 1\right)} e^{\left(-t\right)} & \frac{1}{4} \, {\left(e^{\left(4 \, t\right)} - 1\right)} e^{\left(-t\right)} & \frac{1}{4} \, {\left(e^{\left(4 \, t\right)} - 1\right)} e^{\left(-t\right)} \\
\frac{1}{4} \, {\left(e^{\left(4 \, t\right)} - 1\right)} e^{\left(-t\right)} & \frac{1}{4} \, {\left(e^{\left(4 \, t\right)} + 3\right)} e^{\left(-t\right)} & \frac{1}{4} \, {\left(e^{\left(4 \, t\right)} - 1\right)} e^{\left(-t\right)} & \frac{1}{4} \, {\left(e^{\left(4 \, t\right)} - 1\right)} e^{\left(-t\right)} \\
\frac{1}{4} \, {\left(e^{\left(4 \, t\right)} - 1\right)} e^{\left(-t\right)} & \frac{1}{4} \, {\left(e^{\left(4 \, t\right)} - 1\right)} e^{\left(-t\right)} & \frac{1}{4} \, {\left(e^{\left(4 \, t\right)} + 3\right)} e^{\left(-t\right)} & \frac{1}{4} \, {\left(e^{\left(4 \, t\right)} - 1\right)} e^{\left(-t\right)} \\
\frac{1}{4} \, {\left(e^{\left(4 \, t\right)} - 1\right)} e^{\left(-t\right)} & \frac{1}{4} \, {\left(e^{\left(4 \, t\right)} - 1\right)} e^{\left(-t\right)} & \frac{1}{4} \, {\left(e^{\left(4 \, t\right)} - 1\right)} e^{\left(-t\right)} & \frac{1}{4} \, {\left(e^{\left(4 \, t\right)} + 3\right)} e^{\left(-t\right)}
\end{array}\right)
$$

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it is to use the minimal polynomial and Lagrange interpolation. Calculating $A^2$ we notice that $A^2=3I+2A$, hence, $A^2-2A-3I=0$. It means that
$$
\pi_A(x)=x^2-2x-3=(x+1)(x-3)
$$
annihilates $A$, i.e. $\pi_A(A)=0$. Let's decompose the function $e^{tx}$ as
$$
e^{tx}=q(x)\pi_A(x)+r(x).
$$
If we manage to do that (with $q$, $r$ analytical near zeros of $\pi_A$) then
$$
e^{tA}=q(A)\pi_A(A)+r(A)=q(A)\cdot 0+r(A)=r(A).
$$
Since $\pi_A$ is of degree 2 it is enough to search for $r$ of degree 1 in the form $r(x)=ax+b$. To find $a,b$ we can use interpolation conditions at $x=-1$ and $x=3$:
$$
e^{-t}=r(-1)=-a+b,\qquad e^{3t}=r(3)=3a+b.
$$
Solving the system of 2 equations and 2 unknowns gives
$$
a=\frac{e^{3t}-e^{-t}}{4},\qquad b=\frac{e^{3t}-e^{-t}}{4}+e^{-t},
$$
that is 
$$
r(x)=ax+b=\frac{e^{3t}-e^{-t}}{4}(x+1)+e^{-t}.
$$
Finally (with $x=A$)
$$
e^{tA}=\frac{e^{3t}-e^{-t}}{4}(A+I)+e^{-t}I.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$A^2=3I+2A$, so $e^{tA}$ is a linear combination of $I$ and $A$:
$$e^{tA}=f(t)I+g(t)A.$$
But the derivative of $e^{tA}$ is $Ae^{tA}$:
$$f'(t)I+g'(t)A=f(t)A+g(t)(2A+3I)=3g(t)I+(f(t)+2g(t))A.$$
We get the system of differential equations
\begin{align}
f'(t)&=3g(t)\\
g'(t)&=f(t)+2g(t)
\end{align}
with initial conditions $f(0)=1$ and $g(0)=0$. We get the second-order
equation for $g(t)$:
$$g''(t)-2g'(t)-3g(t)=0.$$
Solve this, use initial conditions to find arbitrary constants, and extract
$f(t)=g'(t)-2g(t)$ from it....